# CSV and Jinja2 templates: adding column headers to CSV data

Tags: python, csv, jinja2

I want to read in a CSV file, push it through a Jinja2 template file then print the result.
My problem is that I need to specify a column name in the template (such as data.name, data.age etc.)
I am not clear on how to allocate a column name to the CSV I have read in.
CSV file:

```
David,34,Builder
Carol,55,Architect
John,25,Programmer
```

Template file:

```
{% for data in data%}
 Name is {{ data.name}}, age is {{ data.age}}, job is {{ data.job}}.
 {%- endfor %}
```

Python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
import csv

with open('in.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    data = list(reader)

print(data)

file_loader = FileSystemLoader('./')
env = Environment(loader=file_loader)
template = env.get_template('testa.tmpl')

output = template.render(data=data)
print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using csv.DictReader:

```
reader = csv.DictReader(f,fieldnames =("name","age","job"))
data = list(reader)
print(data)
```